# Create a 0.5px uiview border in non-retina device

Tags: ios, core-graphics, border

I tried to create a view's border using this code:

```
view.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
view.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
```

Depending the device's orientation, I see it or not. If I use 1.0px border it works perfectly.
I'm using a non retina device. I have to support both screens, retina and non-retina.

Any idea?

Thanks

**EDIT**

This is an example of what I mean. I added an UIView and set borders with code above.
[image: Only two borders shown]

Comment: `it works perfectly.`.. Then what is your question?

Comment: @Mani Maybe I am wrong. Is it possible to create a 0.5px border in a non retina device? Because I have tested with both screens and I realized that with retina, my question works but it doesn't with non-retina.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like:

```
view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0 / view.window.screen.scale;
```

Comment: Testing your solution with retina and non-retina devices, I realized that 0.5px line is supported only in retina devices. Am I wrong? Thanks for your response